# Hot to use group by dateime with a gap of 2 seconds?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, group-by

I have a table with data:

```
id          created              price    amount
2204155 2011-12-15 17:08:11.163   71       54150
2204156 2011-12-15 17:08:11.177   71       54150
2204157 2011-12-15 17:08:11.177   71       54150
2204158 2011-12-15 17:08:11.177   71       54150
```

I have a sql query:

```
select created, price, amount 
  from table 
  group by created, price, amount
```

Result:

```
created                 price   amount
2011-12-15 17:08:11.163   71    54150
2011-12-15 17:08:11.177   71    54150
```

I'd like to receive single line.
Is it possible in group by section define created with a gap of 2 seconds to fit in same group?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic math teaches us that if you have an even number, adding or subtracting 1 from it produces an odd number. By extension, any two adjacent odd numbers are +/- 2 from each other; for example, the gap between 3 seconds and 5 seconds is 2 seconds.

Slightly more advanced math teaches us about [Modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic); for the sake of this answer, all you really need to know is that `any number % 2` (the `%` symbol is often used to represent the mod operator) will return either a 1 or a 0, indicating whether the number is even or odd.

What this means is that we can create a statement that says 'Take the second value of a `datetime` column and check to see whether it is even or odd. If it is even, add 1 second to the `datetime` value and output it; if it is odd, output the unchanged `datetime`

This produces an output where each `datetime` value is rounded up to the nearest odd second, meaning that a `GROUP BY` on that `datetime` value will produce aggregates for two-second intervals.

Sample code follows:

```
declare @testing_table table (amount int, whentime datetime)

insert into @testing_table
select * from 
(
select 1 as amount, '2012-01-25 16:53:44.437' as whentime

union
select 2, '2012-01-25 16:53:45.437'

union
select 3, '2012-01-25 16:53:46.437'

union
select 5, '2012-01-25 16:53:47.437'

union
select 7, '2012-01-25 16:53:48.437'

union 
select 11, '2012-01-25 16:53:49.437'

) workingtbl



select SUM(amount), grouptime
from
(
    select amount, case when isodd = 0 then DATEADD(second, 1, whentime) else whentime end as grouptime
    from
    (
        SELECT *, datepart(second,whentime)%2 as isOdd
        from
        @testing_table
    ) oddparse
)groupsum
group by grouptime
```

Initial input:

```
amount  whentime
1       2012-01-25 16:53:44.437
2       2012-01-25 16:53:45.437
3       2012-01-25 16:53:46.437
5       2012-01-25 16:53:47.437
7       2012-01-25 16:53:48.437
11      2012-01-25 16:53:49.437
```

Final output:

```
(No column name)    grouptime
3                   2012-01-25 16:53:45.437
8                   2012-01-25 16:53:47.437
18                  2012-01-25 16:53:49.437
```

Comment: Thank you. Modified line and got what i need: 'select amount, case when isodd = 0 then DATEADD(second, 1, DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, whentime)) else DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, whentime) end as grouptime'

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, created), created) AS created, 
    price, 
    amount 
FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY 
    DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, created), created), 
    price, 
    amount
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do this specifically in SQL Server, but in MySQL you can use `DATE_FORMAT()` not only to `SELECT` a date in a specific format, but also to group on. In your case I guess you'd want to format your dates in a structure like `2011-12-15 17:08` (eg `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM`) which would group by minute. Not sure how you could break it down into two seconds though.